How to use Worker threads?
Recently I've create and app and needed to use workers in it but faced some annoying problem.
So, here is an example of how I use it. Everything looks like it works fine, but it seems that worker couldn't pick up any vite's configuration. Because of that my aliased import not working in worker scope, and also I need to pass execArgv: ["--require", "ts-node/register"], in order to compile it properly.
Example:
const w = new Worker(
  new URL(process.cwd() + "/src/workers/testScript.ts", import.meta.url),
  {
    execArgv: ["--require", "ts-node/register"],
  }
);

w.on("message", (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});

Is there any way to fix that?
